# Anaconda continue installation on Linux

Tags: anaconda

I was installing anaconda for my Ubuntu 18.04 machine but I happened to exit the terminal accidentally after a couple of hours. I wish to resume the installation process at that step where it was installing various packages like sklearn, qt, etc.

I get the following error when I run `bash Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh` and give the path where I want my conda home to be (not the default home folder)

```
ERROR: File or directory already exists: '<path_to_anaconda>/anaconda3'
If you want to update an existing installation, use the -u option.
```

How do I approach this error? How do I recover from partial installation?

Also `conda update --all` gives an error `conda:command not found`

Comment: I don't think you can restart the installation where it left off. I'm surprised that it was taking a few hours though! It should only take a few minutes (maybe 10 tops, I think).